# Python 3 - From list to exact string (like list)

Tags: python

I have:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

And I want the exact string:

```
string = "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"
```

Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Represent it:

```
>>> repr([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
'[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'
```